# git deleted by mistake, how to restore it?

Tags: git

I just executed `git reset --hard` by mistake. All my files are lost. How can I recover them?
There are a lot of new files that I wrote here. If I can't restore them, then I will be miserable.

When I use the `git reflog` cpmmand it shows:

```
e1074bb HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to workbranch
e1074bb HEAD@{1}: clone: from https://gitee.com/yujie-cui/gem5.git
```

Why doesn't it record my reset operation?

What can I do now?

Comment: Any working directory changes that you've made and haven't executed a Git command that records an object for (e.g. `commit`, `stash`) are irrecoverable I believe.

Comment: (even `git add`... which would save them as dangling objects)

Comment: If you didn't either stash or commit your work, _and_ your local IDE doesn't have a local history, then sadly your work may be gone for good.

Comment: `git reflog` doesn't record your reset operation because `git reset --hard` does not change git's view of the repository; rather, it changes the working directory.

Answer (score 2):

> I just executed git reset --hard by mistake. All my files are lost. How can I recover them? There are a lot of new files that I wrote here. If I can't restore them, then I will be miserable.

Some potentially destructive things you do with Git give you a chance to change your mind first. Others just do it; Git assumes you know this is dangerous and just obeys. `reset --hard` is one of those.

`reset --hard` returns your working tree and your index to the exact state of the HEAD commit, and if you had any local changes (new files, edits, whatever) that you never committed, they are absolutely gone. If you did some *other* sort of backup, such as Time Machine on a Mac, maybe they are there. Or, as you've been told in a comment, maybe you're working in an IDE that keeps a separate historical record. But that is not the purview of Git.

The lesson here: always add-and-commit before doing just about anything. The only thing Git always preserves for you is commits.

Comment: This definitely taught me a painful lesson. Fortunately, I found my original version on another  server. Hope that there are not many lost files. thank you all!